# was not found in the chain configured namespaces symfony2 500 internal server error production only in env

Tags: php, symfony, orm

my production server is returning a 500 internal server error and the error in app/logs/prod.log states:

```
The class 'Webfoam\bundlenameZ\Entity\Page' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

  Webfoam\bundlenameX\Entity, 
  Webfoam\bundlenameY\Entity, 
  AnotherWeb\WebBundle\Entity, 
  ThisisAnother\AnotherBundle\Entity

  at doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 37
```

when i visit mysites app_dev.php I don't see any error and my orm mapping is set to automapping true.

(I don't have access to the php server I can't write console commands)

Comment: remove the cache/prod directory and try again.

Comment: I have done deleting but now it throw's an error Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message UnexpectedValueException.php on line 51

Comment: It's all good now thank you i spend about 4 hours on this error wew